# document.querySelector return string instead of number

Tags: button, sum

i have two input type fields and i want to take the sum

this is my html:
...

```
<input type="text" id="pos" autocomplete='off' placeholder="pos"></br>
<input type="text" id="cash" autocomplete='off' placeholder="cash"></br>
<button id="button">submit</button>
```

...

and my js:

```
document.querySelector('#button').addEventListener('click',()=>sum());
function sum() {
    var p=document.querySelector('#pos').value;
    var c= document.querySelector('#cash').value;
    let sum=p+c;
    console.log(sum);
}
```

if i insert p=100 and c=200 i get sum=100200 insteal of 300

Comment: Values in HTML are always strings, you can use `parseInt` to turn strings into numbers. [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Html:
it should input type = number instead of text and parseInt function in js

```
<input type="number" id="pos" autocomplete='off' placeholder="pos"></br>
<input type="number" id="cash" autocomplete='off' placeholder="cash"></br>
<button id="button">submit</button>
```

js:

```
document.querySelector('#button').addEventListener('click',()=>sum());
function sum() {
    var p= parseInt(document.querySelector('#pos').value);
    var c= parseInt(document.querySelector('#cash').value);
    let sum=p+c;
    console.log(sum);
}
```